# Cannot get the PID of a web server

Tags: bash, go, process

I have a simple Go web server:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "strings"
)

func sayHello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    message := r.URL.Path
    message = strings.TrimPrefix(message, "/")
    message = "Hello " + message
    w.Write([]byte(message))
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", sayHello)
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

And a Makefile that runs it and caches the PID to a PID file:

```
GOSRC=$(wildcard *.go)
.PHONY: kill
kill:
    echo ""
.PHONY: neaten
neaten:
    go clean
    go mod tidy
    go mod download
    goimports -w $(GOSRC)
    go vet $(GOSRC)
    go test -cover $(GOSRC)
.PHONY: build
build: neaten
    go build -o server $(GOSRC)
.PHONY: run
run: kill build
    nohup ./server &
    echo $! > server.pid
```

However, `echo $!` does not work for some reason, what I get is an empty server.pid file.
The process is definitely running since I can access the web server. But `echo $!` doesn't do anything.

I have also tried `echo $$` but that also doesn't do much.

I'm also running the Makefile from the fish terminal.

Comment: Does running those nohup and echo commands work if done manually in the shell?

Comment: Not for the fish terminal... But that shouldn't matter since I do ``SHELL := /bin/bash``

Comment: Side comments - (1) as noted by 'volker' Makefile is not a good platform for launching a server. Consider, as alternative, create 'server.sh'. (2) Also, consider extending the server to write the server.pid file once it successfully start serving requests.

Comment: @dash-o I ended up moving the nohup command to an sh file as it was the only way I could get it running properly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run command from `make`, each command is executed in a separate shell:

```
run: kill build
    nohup ./server &
    echo $! > server.pid
```

The 'nohup' will execute in one shell, and `echo` will be executed in a different shell. As a result, the PID of the back grounded process ($!) is available in the first line, but NOT in the second.

The simple solution is to place the two command on the same line.

```
run: kill build
    nohup ./server &  echo $! > server.pid
```

Comment: I'm getting a ``Syntax error: "&&" unexpected`` but your logic makes sense...

Comment: I have also tried ``(nohup ./server &) && echo $! > server.pid`` which echoes nothing as well...

Comment: I also set ``SHELL:=/bin/bash`` but that also doesn't work...

Comment: I think it's just `&` between the commands instead of `& &&`.

Comment: @Whiteclaws - Sorry, just remove the &&. Just '&' will work. It not possible to combine background and '&&', since '&&' will need the status code.

Comment: Makefiles are unsuitable as runscripts.